# How do I render a subset of a texture (knowing the size in pixels) in a OpenGL/WebGL Fragment Shader?

Tags: opengl-es, dart, webgl, shader, fragment-shader

I've got some code that is rendering 2D sprites to the screen. It all works; but the texture coords are provided in the range `0,0 - 1,1`. I would like to supply the coordinates in pixels, so that when I'm creating a sprite, I can provide the part of the sprite sheet to render in pixels (otherwise, if my spritesheet ever changes size, I'd need to re-calculate all the locations, which doesn't seem normal).

```dart
// IDEAL SPRITE INIT CODE
var player = new Sprite(
  position: new Vector2.zero(),
  velocity: new Vector2.zero(),
  size: new Vector2(128.0, 128.0) // Rendered size in world-units
  texture: player2Texture,
  textureOffset: new Vector2.zero(), // Offset in spritesheet
  textureSize: new Vector2(100, 100), // Size of section of spritesheet to render
);
```

I could pass in the total size of the texture here, and divide by it, to get numbers in the range 0-1, but I can't see whether the Texture in WebGL gives me access to this (nor am I sure it's the normal thing to do).

I'm trying to do as much calculation in the shader as possible (I presume this is logical, since GPUs tend to be faster than CPUs, but like I say, I'm a noob, please point out if this is silly!), and my current shaders look like this:

```c
# VERTEXT SHADER
uniform vec2 uResolution;

attribute vec2 aSpriteLocation;
attribute vec2 aSpriteSize;
attribute vec2 aVertexPosition;
attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;
attribute vec2 aTextureSize;

varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
varying vec2 vTextureSize;

void main() {
  // Convert from screen coords to clipSpace (-1,-1 to 1,1)
  vec2 clipSpace = (((aSpriteLocation + (aVertexPosition * aSpriteSize)) / uResolution) * 2.0) - 1.0;

  // Flip upside down, so 0,0 is at the top of the screen!
  clipSpace = clipSpace * vec2(1, -1);

  gl_Position = vec4(clipSpace, 0.0, 1.0);
  vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;
  vTextureSize = aTextureSize;
}
```

```c
# FRAGMENT SHADER
#ifdef GL_ES
precision highp float;
#endif

uniform sampler2D uSampler;

varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
varying vec2 vTextureSize; # Currently this must be in the range 0,0 - 1,1; but I want to pass in texture pixels

void main() {
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(uSampler, vTextureSize * vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t));
}
```

Currently the `vTextureSize` that makes it to my fragment shader works in the range `0,0 - 1,1`. What is the correct way to be able to supply pixel-coords for my texture and have them mapped somewhere?

I thought there might be a common/standard shader set used for basic 2D rendering that would already have a bunch of uniforms/attributes I could just provide, but I've been unable to find one. However, if such things exist, I'd love to know (since I haven't even gotten to rotation, alpha, tinting and other things I might want to do on sprites ;-))

Answer (score 0):

Although I couldn't find any samples doing it when I posted; taking in the full TextureSize and dividing by it might not be unusual; the XNA SpriteBatch shader [is here online](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/utility/spritebatch_shader) and does just that. This might be a good starting point in the absense of any others! :)

(Including source below for convenience, as it's wrapped up in a zip at the provided link. The licence is [MS-PL](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/downloads/?id=15))

```c
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// SpriteBatch.fx
//
// Microsoft XNA Community Game Platform
// Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------


// Input parameters.
float2   ViewportSize    : register(c0);
float2   TextureSize     : register(c1);
float4x4 MatrixTransform : register(c2);
sampler  TextureSampler  : register(s0);


#ifdef XBOX360


// Vertex shader for rendering sprites on Xbox.
void SpriteVertexShader(int        index          : INDEX,
                        out float4 outputPosition : POSITION0,
                        out float4 outputColor    : COLOR0,
                        out float2 outputTexCoord : TEXCOORD0)
{
    // Read input data from the vertex buffer.
    float4 source;
    float4 destination;
    float4 originRotationDepth;
    float4 effects;
    float4 color;

    int vertexIndex = index / 4;
    int cornerIndex = index % 4;

    asm
    {
        vfetch source,              vertexIndex, texcoord0
        vfetch destination,         vertexIndex, texcoord1
        vfetch originRotationDepth, vertexIndex, texcoord2
        vfetch effects,             vertexIndex, texcoord3
        vfetch color,               vertexIndex, texcoord4
    };

    // Unpack into local variables, to make the following code more readable.
    float2 texCoordPosition = source.xy;
    float2 texCoordSize = source.zw;

    float2 position = destination.xy;
    float2 size = destination.zw;

    float2 origin = originRotationDepth.xy;
    float rotation = originRotationDepth.z;
    float depth = originRotationDepth.w;

    // Which of the four sprite corners are we currently shading?
    float2 whichCorner;

    if      (cornerIndex == 0) whichCorner = float2(0, 0);
    else if (cornerIndex == 1) whichCorner = float2(1, 0);
    else if (cornerIndex == 2) whichCorner = float2(1, 1);
    else                       whichCorner = float2(0, 1);

    // Calculate the vertex position.
    float2 cornerOffset = (whichCorner - origin / texCoordSize) * size;

    // Rotation.
    float cosRotation = cos(rotation);
    float sinRotation = sin(rotation);

    position += mul(cornerOffset, float2x2(cosRotation, sinRotation, -sinRotation, cosRotation));

    // Apply the matrix transform.
    outputPosition = mul(float4(position, depth, 1), transpose(MatrixTransform));

    // Half pixel offset for correct texel centering.
    outputPosition.xy -= 0.5;

    // Viewport adjustment.
    outputPosition.xy /= ViewportSize;
    outputPosition.xy *= float2(2, -2);
    outputPosition.xy -= float2(1, -1);

    // Texture mirroring.
    whichCorner = lerp(whichCorner, 1 - whichCorner, effects);

    // Compute the texture coordinate.
    outputTexCoord = (texCoordPosition + whichCorner * texCoordSize) / TextureSize;

    // Simple color output.
    outputColor = color;
}


#else


// Vertex shader for rendering sprites on Windows.
void SpriteVertexShader(inout float4 position : POSITION0,
                        inout float4 color    : COLOR0,
                        inout float2 texCoord : TEXCOORD0)
{
    // Apply the matrix transform.
    position = mul(position, transpose(MatrixTransform));

    // Half pixel offset for correct texel centering.
    position.xy -= 0.5;

    // Viewport adjustment.
    position.xy /= ViewportSize;
    position.xy *= float2(2, -2);
    position.xy -= float2(1, -1);

    // Compute the texture coordinate.
    texCoord /= TextureSize;
}


#endif


// Pixel shader for rendering sprites (shared between Windows and Xbox).
void SpritePixelShader(inout float4 color : COLOR0, float2 texCoord : TEXCOORD0)
{
    color *= tex2D(TextureSampler, texCoord);
}


technique SpriteBatch
{
    pass
    {
        VertexShader = compile vs_1_1 SpriteVertexShader();
        PixelShader  = compile ps_1_1 SpritePixelShader();
    }
}
```